# Error importing pictures into an Excel file using ClosedXML

Tags: excel, image, openxml, closedxml

I have a problem with importing pictures in Excel. I usually use ClosedXML, but it cannot import pictures and first have to be saved in ClosedXML, and open in OpenXML, to insert a picture. As a result, when you open a file, I get an error.

> "We found a problem with some content in 'error.xlsx'. Do you want us
>   to try recover much as we can? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, click Yes."

If I save a picture in the Excel file already manually create everything works fine. The problem occurs when you save after ClosedXML.

Comment: See this for an example how it can work: http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/11/30/how-to-insert-an-image-in-excel-open-xml/

Comment: I'm using this one: <http://user239.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-insert-image-to-excel-document.htm>